# i wrote a code for sum of series but i am not getting any output

Tags: c

The question was to add first seven terms of the following series using for loop
1/1! + 2/2! + 3/3! ....
I thought i might be loosing decimal point due to int but i am not even getting wrong answer.
I ran the code in terminal but it just keeps running no output.
Thanks for helping out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    float a;
    float v=0.0;
    for(n=1;n<=7;n++)
    {
        a=1.0;
        while(n>0)
        {
            a=a/n;
            n--;
        }
        v=v+n*a;
    }
    printf(" sum is %f ",v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'just keeps running...' because you incremented the value of n initially only to decrease the value inside the loop, causing the value of n to go back and forth repeatedly and thus the loop runs repeatedly...

Comment: sorryy I got it now thanks

Comment: If you have answered your own question, you can answer it and accept the answer to aid other SO users.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int n) {
    int product = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        product *= i;
    }
    return product;
}

int main() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 7+1; i++) {
        sum += double(i) / fact(i);
    }
    printf("Sum is %f\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I copied your code in visual studio but it shows error at double [sum += double(i) / fact(i);]. I have recently started c so i dont know double yet.

Comment: double is type of data that stores high-precision floating-point data. It is called double data type because it can hold the double size of data compared to the float data type.

Comment: This would be a much better answer with some explanation of what you've done and how it resolves the issue the OP is having.

Comment: First I declared a variable sum with a double data type to hold floating point numbers. Then I iterate through 1 to 7 using a for loop, and at each iteration, I calculate the value of i divided by its factorial where i is 1..7, before adding it to the sum variable. Then, I print out the sum. For the fact function, I will calculate the value of the factorial of the argument by multiplying 1 with the next integer again and again until the next integer is the argument itself. Thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The series is `1/1! + 2/2! + .. n terms` can be written as `1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + ...(n-1) terms` .

So it is `1` + `sum of 1/i! where i=1 to i=n-1 terms`.

So I have taken `sum=1` as initial value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//this is the function for calculating n!
int fact(int n) {
    int product = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        product *= i;
    }
    return product;
}

int main() {

    int n=5;

    //we are taking sum=1 as initial value
    double sum = 1.0;

    //now we run 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! i.e. upto (n-1) terms (here n=5 => so n-1 = 4)
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        sum += (1.0) / fact(i);
    }

    printf("Sum is %f\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's not a lot of explanation, and then a big chunk of code. This answer could be improved.

Comment: what's missing? can you tell so that I can edit my answer

Comment: How did the information you presented at the beginning of your answer influence the code you wrote? How is it different from the OP's code? How does it solve their problem?

Comment: I guess I have explained it already

Comment: with this code output sum is 2.708333, whereas in my code i am getting sum as 2.718056

Answer (score 0):

As @DeBARtha mentioned in the original code i was incrementing and then decreasing n causing to loop to run repeatedly.
By using one more variable (m) for the while loop and then decreasing it while increasing the 'n' in the for loop  the problem gets resolved.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,m;
    float a;
    float v=0.0;
    for(n=1;n<=7;n++)
    {
        m=n;
        a=1.0;
        while(m>0)
        {
            a=a/m;
            m--;
        }
        v=v+n*a;
    }
    printf(" sum is %f ",v);
    return 0;
}
```